# Jquery Dialog calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

When i click on button to show the message i get one MessageBox that's normal but when i call the Jquery Dialog for second time i get two MessageBoxs! and when i call Jquery Dialog for third time i get three MessageBoxs!
Please help me!

Here is my Code:

```
        $("[id*=Call_Dialog]").live("click", function () {
            $("#MyDiv").dialog({
                title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#ShowMessage").live("click", function () {                       
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('Hi');
                $("#MyDiv").dialog('close');
            })
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="MyDiv" style="display: none">
        This is a simple popup

<asp:Button ID="ShowMessage" runat="server" Text="Button" /> 


    </div>

    </form>
    <p>
        <input id="Call_Dialog" type="button" value="button" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Include your scripts at the end of the body for better performance
2. Use "bind" instead of "live" if your elements are not dynamic.
3. If your elements are dynamic use "on" instead of "live".

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MX9Dk/

Made some amends and its working fine for me.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="MyDiv" style="display: none">
        This is a simple popup
        <asp:Button ID="ShowMessage" runat="server" Text="Button" /> 
    </div>
</form>

    <p>
        <input id="call-dialog" type="button" value="button" />
    </p>



$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#call-dialog").click(function () {
             $("#MyDiv").dialog({
                title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        });

       $("#ShowMessage").live("click", function () {                       
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('Hi');
                $("#MyDiv").dialog('close');
       });

 });
```